How to pass float or double parameters to C functions in AArch64 assembly
I was trying to make a counter which add from 0.0 to 1, I first implement the counter via fadd, then I have trouble to print floating point number.
Platform: Alpine Linux Aarch64 (3.20.2), GNU Binutils (2.42) (Running from a VM on my M2 Mac)
.global _start
.extern printf

.data
    string: .asciz "Hello World! %f\n" // Store String
    f: .float 1.132 // Store the float 1.132

.text

_start:

loop:
    ldr x0, =string // Load String into x0
    ldr d1, =f // Load float into d1 (A float reg)

    bl printf // Call printf in glibc
    b exit // Branch to exit label

exit:
    mov x8, #93 // Exit SYSCALL
    mov x0, #0 // Exit code
    svc 0 // Syscall

build.sh
as main.s -o main.o
ld -lc --dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 main.o -o main

Output
Hello World! 0.00000


Author: I have also post it in the sub reddit r/Assembly_language and someone kindly help out.
So basically, I need to load the ADDR into a X reg, then I need to load the value into the S reg, finally I can use fcvt (Floating-point Convert precision (scalar)) to transfer the value into the D reg, which are use by the Glibc printf function.
Code:
.global _start
.extern printf

.data
    format: .asciz "%f\n"
    f:  .float 1.123

.text
_start:
    ldr x0, =format
    ldr x2, =f
    ldr s0, [x2]
    fcvt d0, s0
    mov x1, #0
    
    bl printf

    mov x8, #93
    mov x0, #0
    svc 0


float promoting to double is specific to variadic or unprototyped functions like printf in C (How to print a single-precision float with printf).   A "normal" function with a prototyped float arg would take an actual float arg in an S register.
